# column value in datagridview

Tags: c#

i use these following codes to get cell's value in datagridview.
these codes show me each cell has been clicked. 
i want to use some codes just show me special column for example column with index 1 but these codes show me each which has been clicked. Imagine i just want to show column 1 with it's clicked cell. please help me to solve this

```
string str = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're trying to get the data from the second column for every row?

```
int index = 1;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[index];
    // Do something.
}
```

**Edit:** Per your comment, you're trying to get the value of the second column when any cell in the row is clicked.  Try this:

```
string str = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: i got a problem with this code. when i click on each cell it will show me all rows with column 1 index

Comment: btw it starts from the first row. not a specific row

Comment: Edited - Was hard to understand your original question.

Comment: column index 1 with that clicked cell's row